# Rabbitmq Consumer Issue

Tags: rabbitmq, consumer, php-amqplib

I just want my consumer to be up and ready when a message comes. I used 'nohup php consumer.php' , it's kind of working but consumer disappearing again. My question is how to keep the consumer ready all the time ?

I tried `nohup php consumer.php` to run my consumer script all the time but not working.
All of docs telling just `PHP consumer.php` and assuming it's working, but that is not a solution. I am stuck and needing help.

Comment: "_consumer disappearing again_" - If the process quits when you log out, then try running the process in the background with `nohup php consumer.php &`. See [What does the ampersand (&) symbol mean with `nohup`?](https://serverfault.com/q/402496) on Server Fault.

Comment: Otherwise what is in the `nohup` log file? Any relevant information?

Comment: @andrewJames thanks for reply. I found the reason why the consumer process stop. It's because of 'exit' keyword at the end of consumer.php. It stops the process of consumer script.